# Angular 2, Webpack 2, async routes: Cannot find module

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, routes

I've been working with my repo for a while, it's a clone of the [angular2-seed repo](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-seed.git). It includes webpack 2 (I think it's still beta) and async routes.

I did some tests and reverted to a previous state, but after installing packages with npm it fails loading async components with the following message in the browser:

```
browser_adapter.js:85 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module './+tickets'.
```

The plus sign is not a typo, the folder is actually called "+tickets" and it contains an index.ts file. It always worked, and now for some reason it doesn't.

I tried everything, but the error is so clueless that I don't know where to watch. Maybe the webpack-dev-server is not serving the files correctly..?

An alternative plan would be to start everything from scratch and then move the modules, but I'm really interested to where the problem is for future implementations.

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Please share your webpack config and also how you are doing import.

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/JB5x3f0q and it imports with `LoadChildren: './+tickets'`

Comment: how are you importing this module and how are you exporting this? would be easy to see some more code to find what's wrong..

Comment: The main module and the async routes are completely disconnected, there is no import. Everything goes fine until, in the main module (which contains the routes), one route calls LoadChildren and this is supposed to request additional stuff from the server. The web client tells that it's not found, I think it's because maybe Webpack doesn't compile it. Anyway I switched to standard routing for now, there is no absolute need for a fix. Just wanted to ask if anybody encountered a similar error. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I've created Angular2 lazy loading demo using RC 6.

Please checkout https://github.com/Quramy/ng2-lazy-load-demo .